# Docker - Remove file added from previous stage

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a container running [caddy](https://hub.docker.com/layers/abiosoft/caddy/latest/images/sha256-6f90597617b16108805ca30e4a7a1daaacf0a763110514560b9ca2dc3c3f4ca0?context=explore)

I am trying to remove the file added at the step 16 in the Dockerfile, I have something like that in my Dockerfile

```
FROM abiosoft/caddy:1.0.3

RUN rm /srv/index.html
RUN ls
>> index.html
```

Do we have a solution to remove a file added in the previous steps? Or my only solution is to "fork" the Dockerfile and remove this line?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the image history from your link, you'll see line 13

```
VOLUME [/root/.caddy /srv]
```

That `VOLUME` directive means that `RUN` commands afterwards can't modify that directory at all.  You'll see exactly the result you're reporting: the `RUN` command will apparently run successfuly, and within that single `RUN` command you'll see files changed, but it won't persist across runs.

```sh
RUN rm /srv/index.html \
 && echo 'ls -l in same RUN line' \
 && ls -l /srv
RUN echo 'ls -l in separate RUN line' \
 && ls -l /srv
```

There's no way to undo this without forking the original Dockerfile.

Comment: Here is lin to the official documentation that proofs this - https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#notes-about-specifying-volumes

Answer (score 0):

There is another option than a fork of the Dockerfile. You can mount the `src` while running a container and it will rewrite what is inside the volume. For instance, `docker run ... -v /path/to/php/src:/srv ...` will put inside the container files (file structure) that is inside `/path/to/php/src`.

Comment: Ok but I have some files from a previous stage to put here too. (I make 4 react builds in a previous stage and copy the build directories into /srv when it's done).

If I set the volume in my compose.yml or at the startup all the files from this volume will be "replaced"

Comment: @Bast okay, what if don't use `src` at all? I mean that to set new `WORKDIR /my-dir` in the Dockerfile and use it for all `COPY` and other instructions. Does it work for you?